# Why are my JOGL lighting shaders not working?

Tags: java, glsl, jogl, lighting

I am currently working with lighting shaders in JOGL, and they are not working very well.
I dont really know what i did wrong, but the light position is not applying (i think) and overall the light is dropping very weirdly, on the screenshot below you can see my cube render with lighting

The java code to render:

```
@Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        float mod = 0.1f;
        if(keys.contains("w")) player[2]+=mod;
        if(keys.contains("s")) player[2]-=mod;
        if(keys.contains("a")) player[0]+=mod;
        if(keys.contains("d")) player[0]-=mod;

        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelViewMatrix.loadIdentity();
        modelViewMatrix.translate(player[0], player[1], player[2]-6);
        modelViewMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(angle), 1, 1, 1);
        modelViewMatrix.scale(1, 1, 1);

        projectionMatrix.loadIdentity();
        projectionMatrix.makePerspective(90f, (float) frame.getWidth()/frame.getHeight(), 1.5f, 20);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMultMatrixf(FloatBuffer.wrap(projectionMatrix.getMatrix()));

        // Vertices and colors for the cube's faces
        float[][] vertices = {
                {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f},
                {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f},
                {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f},
                {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f},
                {1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f},
                {1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f},
                {1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f},
                {1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f}
        };

        float[][] normals = new float[][] {
                {-1.0000f, 0.0000f, 0.0000f},
                {0.0000f, 0.0000f, -1.0000f},
                {1.0000f, 0.0000f, 0.0000f},
                {0.0000f, 0.0000f, 1.0000f},
                {0.0000f, -1.0000f, 0.0000f},
                {0.0000f, 1.0000f, 0.0000f}
        };
        int[] indices = new int[] {
               1, 2, 0,
               3, 6, 2,
               7, 4, 6,
               5, 0, 4,
               6, 0, 2,
               3, 5, 7,
               1, 3, 2,
               3, 7, 6,
               7, 5, 4,
               5, 1, 0,
               6, 4, 0,
               3, 1, 5
        };
        int errorCode = 0;

        int id = l.getProgramID(gl);
        gl.glUseProgram(id);

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(gl.glGetUniformLocation(id, "modelViewMatrix"), 1, false, modelViewMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(gl.glGetUniformLocation(id, "projectionMatrix"), 1, false, projectionMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);

        gl.glUniform3f(gl.glGetUniformLocation(id, "lightColor"), 1, 1, 1);
        gl.glUniform3f(gl.glGetUniformLocation(id, "lightPosition"), 1, 2, -1);
        gl.glUniform1f(gl.glGetUniformLocation(id, "shininess"), .5f);

        l.setPosition(Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(to1d(vertices)));
        l.setNormal(Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(to1d(normals)));
        l.setColor(Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(new float[] {1, 0, 1}));

        l.bindBuffers(gl);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMultMatrixf(FloatBuffer.wrap(modelViewMatrix.getMatrix()));

        gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(indices));

        errorCode = gl.glGetError();
        if(errorCode != GL2.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            String errorString = new GLU().gluErrorString(errorCode);
            System.err.println("OpenGL error: 1 " + errorString);
        }

        l.disable(gl);
        l.unbindBuffers(gl);
        gl.glUseProgram(0);

        angle += 0.5f;
    }
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 inColor;

out vec3 fragColor;
out vec3 fragNormal;
out vec3 lightVec;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main() {
    vec4 worldPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * worldPos;

    fragNormal = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(inNormal, 0.0)).xyz;
    lightVec = lightPosition;

    fragColor = inColor;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 fragColor;
in vec3 fragNormal;
in vec3 lightVec;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform float shininess;

void main() {
    vec3 norm = normalize(fragNormal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightVec);

    float ndot = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = lightColor * fragColor * ndot;

    outColor = vec4(diffuse, 1.0);
}
```

[image: The result i get:]

Comment: At first, rather ask JOGL specific questions on our official JogAmp forum. Secondly, I advise you to compare your shaders and the rest of your code with our example using shaders: https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java?id=HEAD Finally, using indirect NIO buffers with JOGL works but is less efficient as it forces JOGL to convert them into direct NIO buffers anyway.